# Drag down the formula of IMPORTRANGE that changes the last value into increment value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I have an IMPORTRANGE formula in Google Sheets and want to apply it in the rest of the cells below. When I drag down the formula, it stays the same:

```
=importrange("1jhXCPi6RUf8MD7XoYgQsH-E0x768UtVxE3XY_kBrbkE","OCT!F2")
```

How can I drag a formula and have it automatically increment the value (`OCT!F2` should be change into `OCT!F3` up to `OCT!F118`)?

When I drag down this formula, I want it to be like this.

```
=importrange("1jhXCPi6RUf8MD7XoYgQsH-E0x768UtVxE3XY_kBrbkE","OCT!F3")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `row` formula:

```
"OCT!F3" = "OCT!F" & row(A3)
```

You may also include the range in single `importrange`:

```
"OCT!F2:F500"
```

Be careful: importrange formulas may slow down your sheets.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir. :) I used this pattern importrange:

"OCT!F2:F500" and it works ^_^ thank you so much :)

Comment: @zoe I am looking to import a column (say, F35:F100) from one sheet, but I want it to display horizontally (eg, display everyhing from F35:F100 horizontally starting at C8, D8, etc...). Is that possible? You mentioned a row function but not sure if that will get it to work

Comment: @vytfla I edited the answer - I didn't post the answer.

Comment: @Zoe my mistake! I figured it out using the tranpose function